# Android interstitial ads - closes app when go back

Tags: android, ads, interstitial

I'm using interstitial ad in my android app. When user tap on ad it is redirected to the browser - normal behavior, but when you tap on overview button( 3rd button, square) and chose my app, it shows ad again:

- after that if I press on back button - it closes my app.
- after that if I close interstitial ad by taping on X - it also closes app. 
  the same behavior if I just tap on overview button and then chose my app again and close the Interstitial ad it also closes my app.

I've tried to add in manifest noHistory = true for AdsActivity, no luck((.

Expected result: when you tap on ad, then tap on overview button and chose your app - it should redirect to your app and closes ad, i mean - displays previous screen, screen from what i opened ad.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of events in the ad's lifecycle. You can listen for these events through the AdListener class and do whatever you want.

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked() {
        // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.

    }
});
```

Comment: yeah, you're right, but you cannot close your ad from code and app is closed when you trying  to close ad - following the steps i described.